# OpenLDAP: get `directory` from cn=config

Tags: bash, ldap

How can I get directory for specified **DN** by one `ldapsearch` request?

I mean - I have few databases. **OpenLDAP** configured with `cn=config`. For each DN - it hve own ldif-file, where it's `olcDbDirectory` specified.

Can I obtain `olcDbDirectory` value for each DN?

For backup script - I need to set varibale which contains directory, and this variable changes every time for every DN, wich backuped/restored at this moment.

So - in `bash` I just found solution to create function like:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 getDir () {
 file=`grep -R "$1" /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ | cut -d":" -f 1 | tail -n 1`
 echo $file

 dir=`cat $file | grep "olcDbDirectory" | awk '{print $2}'`
 echo $dir
 }

 getDir testdb;

 $ ./dn.sh
 /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={9}bdb.ldif
 /var/lib/ldap/testdb
```

But this solution seems not tidy... And I'd preffered to use something like:

```
 getDir () {
 dir=`ldapsearch -x -D "cn-root,cn=config" "*somefilter*"
 }
```

Comment: please edit your question to include sample (sanitized) data from your ldapsearch. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
 $ ldapsearch -x -LLL -D 'cn=root,cn=config' -w PassWord -b 'cn=config' '(&(olcDbDirectory=*)(olcSuffix='testdb'))' olcDbDirectory | grep "olcDbDirectory" | cut -d":" -f 2
 /var/lib/ldap/testdb
```

Of in bash function:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 getDir () {

 dirtodel=`ldapsearch -x -LLL -D 'cn=root,cn=config' -w PassWord  -b 'cn=config' '(&(olcDbDirectory=*)(olcSuffix='${1}'))' olcDbDirectory | grep "olcDbDirectory" | cut -d":" -f 2`
 echo $dirtodel
 }

 getDir 'dc=testdb'
```

Result:

```
 $ ./dn.sh
 /var/lib/ldap/testdb
```